# Non-isomorphic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

How to prove that $Z/2\times Z/2$ and $ Z/4$ are not isomorphic?

I think that  $Z/2\times Z/2$ is not cyclic. Hence $Z/2\times Z/2$ and $ Z/4$ are not isomorphic.
Thank you.

Comment: You *think* ${\bf Z}_2\times{\bf Z}_2$ is not cyclic? You aren't sure? How might you decide?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Does  $Z/2\times Z/2$ has an element of order $4$ ?